# after windows 10 automatic actualization GRUB does not appear

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm using windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS for ~1 month, with linux booting from UEFI (i.e. secure boot on, not bios). But yesterday windows installed some automatic actualizations and in the morning I realized that linux does not boot any more (i.e GRUB boot menu does not appear).

1. **How to investigate what is the problem?** - I'm not sure linux partition is OK, or maybe even GRUB is OK, maybe windows just modified some UEFI/bios settings.
2. **How to make Linux run again** with minimal risk that I destroy either linux or windows
3. **How to make sure that it will not happen again** (that is rather question about windows than ubuntu ... but I assume many linux users must have the very same problem with windows ruthless auto-updates)

Comment: If UEFI can you boot ubuntu entry in UEFI boot menu? If Secure boot on, I thought you could only boot from UEFI menu as grub does not chain to Windows correctly yet with Secure boot on. You will not be able to prevent issue as Windows only knows Windows and assumes you must want Windows to be first in UEFI menu. It will reset on updates, some systems seem to reset just on booting.

Comment: ah, sorry I did not know that in UEFI I can choose boot order of operating systems. this is new computer, before I had only BIOS where you can choose boot order for disks but not for systems. So I just changed order and voila, now I'm writing from linux. The hardest part was to find how to restart windows to UEFI menu. Thank's for hint and sorry for noob's question

Comment: If you hold down the **LEFT SHIFT** key during boot, are you able to see the GRUB menu, as before? Cheers, Al